# Show that the sum of two integrals is finite.

Tags: integration, inequality, bounds-of-integration

How to easy show that
\begin{equation} \int_0^1 \frac{1-e^{-x}}{x}dx+\int_1^M\frac{-e^{-x}}{x}dx \end{equation} is less than finite number?

Comment: Note that $\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{1-e^{-x}}{x}$ exists. Hence, the integrand of the first integral can be extended to a continuous function on the closed interval $[0,1]$.

Comment: ...and the second integrand is $\le e^{-x}$ in absolute value on the region of integration. So the answer is "pretty easy"!